# Custom message body for each recipient in docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am using a demo account of Docusign integrating with force.com sites using Apex.
I created a template and want to send two different mail body to two different recipient. I have two roles Agent and Broker.
In Broker mail body I want to use Agent Recipient Name. I can get the name in subject by using [[Agent_UserName]] but not in body. Is there any way to use Merge fields in Mail body.

Answer (score 3):

[Merge fields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#template-email-subject-merge-fields) are not supported in the email Body.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request to send unique Email Subject/Body per recipient. You will have to add the [emailNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters) property for each recipient

```
{
  "status": "created",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "name": "recipient one",
                            "email": "recipientone@acme.com",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "recipientId" : "1",
                            "roleName" : "texter",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs" : [
                                    {
                                        "xPosition" : "100", "yPosition" : "100", "documentId" : "1","pageNumber" : "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "emailNotification": {
                              "emailSubject": "subject for one",
                              "emailBody": "Body for One",
                              "supportedLanguage": "en"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Jane Doe",
                            "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId" : "2",
                            "roleName" : "signer",
                            "tabs": {
                                "signHereTabs" : [
                                    {
                                        "xPosition" : "100", "yPosition" : "200", "documentId" : "1", "pageNumber" : "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "emailNotification": {
                              "emailSubject": "subject for two",
                              "emailBody": "Body for two",
                              "supportedLanguage": "en"
                            }                               
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "documents": [
                {
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "name": "Contract",
                    "fileExtension": "txt",
                    "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
     }       
  ]
}
```